# SQL like maximum function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a dataframe such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['a','a','b','b','a'],
           'B' : [1,22,8,3,3]})
```

I need to partition data by `A` and find `max` of `B` in each partition and save the result in a new column `C`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['a','a','b','b','a'],
                   'B' : [1,22,8,3,3],
                   'C' : [22, 22 , 8, 8 , 22]})
```

I have tried

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].max()
```

but this simply only adds a `Nan` column.

Comment: use `transform`: ``df.assign(C = df.groupby('A').B.transform('max'))`` It is sort of equivalent to SQL's partition by

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + `transform`:`

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A   B   C
0  a   1  22
1  a  22  22
2  b   8   8
3  b   3   8
4  a   3  22
```